# When using Amazon API Gateway, how do I get the API key used in the request from a Django backend?

Tags: django, api, amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway

Pretty self explanatory title. I'm using API Gateway in AWS, requiring an API key to access a backend written in Django (not using lambda). I need to know how to access the API key used in the request to keep track of who did what at the app level.

Answer (score 4):

You can use mapping templates and get the API Key from the $context variable, it’s the apiKey property inside the identity object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

Create a mapping template for your requests and include the property in it. For example, if you wanted to include the entire request body + the API Key you would do this:

```
{
  "body": $input.json('$'),
  "apiKey": "$context.identity.apiKey"
}
```

Comment: I'm new to API Gateway. Are you saying that I have to specifically configure API Gateway to allow each request through? For example, if my app took and processed form data, would I need to specifically configure API Gateway to pass that form data through to the application? In your example mapping above, would those two values (body and apiKey) be headers sent to the Django application? How would I access them?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your backend application is built, you could send the API key to your application in a HTTP parameter (path, query string, or header) or in the request body. Please have a read through the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) on how to move data between the two systems.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally made it work. At the top or bottom of the template, include this line.

```json
#set($context.requestOverride.header.x-api-key = $context.identity.apiKey)
```

When your backend receives this request, the api key will be in the header `x-api-key`.

Here is a basic mapping template that just forwards the (json) body and the header.

```json
$input.json("$")
#set($context.requestOverride.header.x-api-key = $context.identity.apiKey)
```

API Gateway uses the X-API-Key header, so I like for my backend to also use that. That way I can use the same testing commands with only the URL being different.